# Stopping IIS websites permanently with PowerShell

Tags: iis, powershell

Stopping websites using Stop-Website is, apparently, not the same as stopping them using the IIS Manager.

```
Stop-Website 'Some site'
iisreset.exe
# site is started again
```

Using IIS Manager, the state is the same after a reset/reboot. I guess stopping a site using IIS Manager modifies some sort of persistent configuration (the registry?).

Can anyone tell me how I can use PowerShell to stop a site permanently, so that a reset/reboot does not bring the site online again?

(Stop-WebAppPool exhibits exactly the same behavior.)

Comment: I assume `Remove-Website` is not what you want to do?

Comment: No, that's a tad too destructive :). This is to temporarily stop a site, but not just until the next reset.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Joseph's answer makes perfect sense, but it doesn't seem to work.

The attribute 'serverAutoStart' on the site node in `applicationHost.config` is not changed.

One way to change is:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.applicationHost/sites/site[@name='Default Web Site']" -name "serverAutoStart" -value "False"
```

but that's a mouthful.

Another way is:

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site" serverAutoStart False
```

It's also interesting that this attribute is not directly editable in IIS Manager, you have to go into the `Configuration Editor` to change it.

Yes, starting or stopping the site in IIS Manager changes that attribute, but that's not obvious to the user.

Comment: Hmmmm ... :D  I wonder if that just modifies it in memory ... Set-ItemProperty seems more canonical anyway. good catch!

Comment: The autostart property is in the IIS Manager, `right click on the web site -> "Manage Web Site" -> "Advanced Settings..." -> "Start Automatically"`

Comment: @JosephKern - Hmm, I don't see that, not on my 2012 R2 or 2016. Under what heading is that listed `General`?

Comment: Not sure why you don't see it ... I have it on 2008R2 IIS7

Comment: @JosephKern - I checked an older server with 2008 R2 and see it there but it's gone in newer versions. I wonder why?

Comment: You can do it all through Powershell now! There's no need to create a UI for anything /s.

Comment: Very nice, thank you. The reason I needed this: I've put together a script that collects all sites running on the specified machines, together with the timestamp for the last request. This is sent to Out-GridView -PassThru, so the user can select zero or more sites which will then be stopped. Handy for dev servers, in our case.

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
    $site = Get-Item 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site'
    $site.serverAutoStart = $False
    $site.Stop()
```

Obviously, `Default Web Site` needs to be replaced. ;-)

I don't have a test lab setup for this, so let me know if it works for you.

There are a ton of options in the IIS PSProvider ... run the following to explore a bit more:

```
    $site = Get-Item 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site'
    $site | get-member
```

Comment: Does not compute, as far as I can tell. serverAutoStart lives in applicationHost.config, and changes to a ConfigurationElement object are not persisted.

Comment: I could probably modify applicationHost.config manually, but that smells all kinds of wrong :).

Comment: See Peters post, Set-ItemProperty looks like what you want. I was oh so close ... ;-)

Comment: @JosephKern - close enough to still get up-votes, :-) This doesn't work kids.

Comment: Upvote was mine, because it was correct in spirit :). The solution is accepted and here for everyone to see, so I don't see the harm in rewarding Joseph's effort.

Comment: So close .... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep yet to comment, so posting this as an answer...

To make Joseph's suggestion work a `Set-Item` is needed to persist the change.

```
    $site = Set-Item
```

The full 4 lines to make default site stay stopped.

```
    $site = Get-Item 'IIS:\sites\Default Web Site'
    $site.serverAutoStart = $False
    $site.Stop()
    $site = Set-Item
```